# Rails - Does Action Cable Require Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sort of new to `Ruby on Rails`. I'm trying to add a real-time chat feature to my school final project, and it seems that `Action Cable` would work well for this.

However, whenever I search for tutorials about how to use `Action Script`, they're always Rails 5 applications. My group and I are using Rails 4.2.6. Does `Action Script` require Rails 5, or can I also use it with Rails 4?

If I can't use it with Rails 4, are there any other gems or techniques that I can use to create a real-time chat feature in my app?

Comment: You can alternatively use the `websocket-rails` gem with rails 4. There are more alternatives, too, such as `faye`. have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes. At the very least it requires `ActiveSupport` 5, which comes with Rails 5.

While there may be a very roundabout way to include ActionCable as a dependency for Rails 4, It wasn't intended to be used with Rails 4 and I would recommend against it for this reason. If you want to use ActionCable, you should upgrade to Rails 5. Otherwise, consider using Faye or another evented messaging framework for chat.

And what do you mean by `Action Script`? Do you mean the Adobe Flash language/framework? If so, this has nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: Woops! Sorry! Mentioned `Action Script` twice was definitely a typo as I meant `Action Cable`. And thanks for the advice on `Faye`. I'll definitely look into that.